# Powershell - aggregate filenames in one directory

Tags: powershell

I have an array which contains values like this:

```
C:\DIR1\FILE1
C:\DIR1\FILE2
C:\DIR2\FILE1
C:\DIR2\FILE2
```

I need to execute a program as follows:

```
EXECUTABLE.exe C:\DIR1 C:\VARDIR FILE1 FILE2
EXECUTABLE.exe C:\DIR2 C:\VARDIR FILE1 FILE2
```

I tried to create a foreach loop, but this will execute four times, instead of two.

Comment: This can be done but please show us what you have tried first.

Answer (score -1):

Remove 'Write-Host' to run EXECUTABLE.exe

```
$arr = 'C:\DIR1\FILE1', 'C:\DIR1\FILE2', 'C:\DIR2\FILE1', 'C:\DIR2\FILE2'
$arr | group {Split-Path $_} | ? count -eq 2 | % {
    $arg1 = Split-Path $_.group[0]
    $arg2 = Split-Path $_.group[0] -Leaf
    $arg3 = Split-Path $_.group[1] -Leaf
    Write-Host EXECUTABLE.exe $arg1 "C:\VARDIR" $arg2 $arg3
}
```